# Compute Takagi group of the extension $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-5})/\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Given an extension $L/K$ of number fields we define the Takagi group as the subgroup $$T_{L/K} = N_{L/K} (D_L) \cdot H_K \subseteq D_K$$ where $N_{L/K}$ is the relative norm, $D_\bullet$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero fractional ideals and $H_\bullet$ is the multiplicative group of principal fractional ideals. For example, if $K$ has class number $1$ then trivially $T_{L/K} \cong D_K$.

I'm interested in trying to compute some less trivial examples, for example the case $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, $L = \mathbb Q(i, \sqrt{-5})$. How would one do this manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, $T_{L/K}$ has index $2$ in $D_K$ by class field theory,
hence we must have $T_{L/K} = H_K$. In fact, the norms of principal 
ideals are principal, but so are the norms of non-principal ideals
in the case at hand: since the class group of $K$ is cyclic of order
$2$ and generated by $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, every nonprincipal ideal has 
the form $(\alpha) \cdot (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, and its norm is a principal
ideal times the norm of $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, which is $(2)$ and thus 
also principal. This proves that $T_{L/K} = H_K$.

For all other quadratic extensions of $K$, the Takagi group is $D_K$ by class field theory.

Comment: OK, cool. A quick question: you've claimed "every nonprincipal ideal has the form $(\alpha) \cdot (2, 1+\sqrt5)$". Aren't these just the ideals of $\mathcal O_K$? Do all the nonprincipal ideals in $\mathcal O_L$ have this form as well?

Comment: The ideals in question are not principal, and are disjoint with $H_K$. The field $L$ has class number $1$  (it is even Euclidean), hence it only contains principal ideals.